# Automapper not mapping List<int>

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I am mapping two objects using AutoMapper but it is not mapping List of `int`.

Here is what I am doing:

```
Public class A
{
    public int a{get;set;}
    public string b{get;set;}
    public List<int> ints{get;set;}
}

Public class B
{
    public int a{get;set;}
    public string b{get;set;}
    public List<int> ints{get;set;}
}

public class MappingService
{

    public object MapBToA(B b)
   {
        Mapper.CreateMap<B,A>();
        return  Mapper.Map<B,A>(b);
   }
}
```

When we call the mapping function it is returning a type  of `object` but ints is always empty.

### Edited

Question With Real Classes

```
public class SearchRawInput
{
    public SearchRawInput()
    {
        PageNo = 1;
    }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Segment1 { get; set; }
    public string Segment2 { get; set; }
    public TargetAgeGroup? TargetAge { get; set; }
    public List<int> CategoryIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> SubCategoryIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> LocationIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> LocationGroupIds { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? StartPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? EndPrice { get; set; }
    public string SearchQuery { get; set; }
    public int? PageNo { get; set; }

}

public class ClassSearchInputViewModel
{
    public ClassSearchInputViewModel()
    {
        PageSize = 12;
    }
    public UrlSeoProcessingResult UrlSeoProcessingResult { get; set; }
    public TargetAgeGroup TargetAge { get; set; }
    public List<int> CategoryIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> SubCategoryIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> LocationIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> LocationGroupIds { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? StartPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? EndPrice { get; set; }
    public ClassDifficultyLevel DifficultyLevel { get; set; }
    public string SearchQuery { get; set; }
    public int PageNo { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}

public class SegmentToUrlSeoProcessingResultResolver : ValueResolver<SearchRawInput, UrlSeoProcessingResult>
{
    protected  override UrlSeoProcessingResult ResolveCore(SearchRawInput source)
    {
        var processor =new UrlProcessor();
        if (source.Segment1 != null && source.Segment2 != null)
        {
            return processor.Process( (source.Segment1.Trim() + "/" + source.Segment2.Trim()).Trim(), source.City);
        }
        else if (source.Segment1 == null && source.Segment2 == null)
        {
            return processor.Process("", source.City);
        }
        else
        {
            if (source.Segment1 != null)
            {
                return processor.Process( (source.Segment1.Trim()).Trim(),source.City);
            }
            else 
            {
                return processor.Process(  source.Segment2.Trim(),source.City);
            }

        }

    }
}


public ClassSearchInputViewModel ClassSearchRawInputToClassSearchInput(SearchRawInput classSearchRawInput)
    {
        var classSearchInput = Mapper.Map<SearchRawInput, ClassSearchInputViewModel>(classSearchRawInput);
        return classSearchInput;
    }

Mapper.CreateMap<SearchRawInput,ClassSearchInputViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UrlSeoProcessingResult, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<SegmentToUrlSeoProcessingResultResolver>());
```

above is the complete code and when i call  ClassSearchRawInputToClassSearchInputmethod it will returl me object of ClassSearchInputViewModel but it returns locationids with 0 not of items

Here is my unit test for the same

```
    [Isolated]
    [TestMethod]
    public void ClassSearchRawInputToClassSearchInputViewModel_Test()
    {

        var urlProcessor = new SegmentToUrlSeoProcessingResultResolver();

        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
        IMapperService mapper = new MapperService();
        int[] genericStringArray = {1, 2, 3};
        var searchRawInput = new SearchRawInput()
            {
                City = "Mumbai",
                Segment1 = "Dance",
                Segment2 = "Salsa",
                CategoryIds =  genericStringArray.ToList(),
                StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                EndDate = DateTime.Now,
                LocationGroupIds = genericStringArray.ToList(),
                LocationIds = genericStringArray.ToList(),
                StartPrice = genericStringArray[0],
                EndPrice = 2132123,
                SearchQuery = "Search Query",
                SubCategoryIds = genericStringArray.ToList(),
                TargetAge = TargetAgeGroup.Kids
            };

        Isolate.NonPublic.WhenCalled(urlProcessor, "ResolveCore", new SearchRawInput()
            {
                City = "Mumbai",
                Segment1 = "Dance",
                Segment2 = "Salsa",
                CategoryIds =  genericStringArray.ToList(),
                StartDate = DateTime.Now,
                EndDate = DateTime.Now,
                LocationGroupIds = genericStringArray.ToList(),
                LocationIds = genericStringArray.ToList(),
                StartPrice = genericStringArray[0],
                EndPrice = 2132123,
                SearchQuery = "Search Query",
                SubCategoryIds = genericStringArray.ToList(),
                TargetAge = TargetAgeGroup.Kids
            }).WillReturn(new UrlSeoProcessingResult()
                                                    {
                                                        LocationGroupId = 1,
                                                        SubCategoryId = 2,
                                                        IsError = false,
                                                        Type = SegmentType.GroupSubCategory
                                                    });
        var classSearchInput = mapper.ClassSearchRawInputToClassSearchInput(searchRawInput);
        Assert.AreEqual(TargetAgeGroup.Kids, classSearchInput.TargetAge, "Age is not mapped properly");
        Assert.AreEqual(3,classSearchInput.LocationIds.Count,"Location not mapped properly");
        Assert.AreEqual(3,classSearchInput.CategoryIds.Count,"Category is not mapped correctly");
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean to call Mapper.Map<B, A>(b);

Comment: yups, i have writte CreateMap by mistake but its still not working

Comment: Why are you calling Mapper.CreateMap everytime you want to map? This method should be called once per AppDomain, ideally when this AppDomain starts.

Comment: it is in app domain only, here i am showing that i had created a map

Comment: @rajansoft1 : Are these classes both `Domain Models` or both are `View Models`? I don;t see any `de-normalization` in any class that shows less Properties in any `View Model`. well that's the big use of `Auto-Mappers` ?

Comment: they are are of view models

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I am unable to reproduce the problem you are describing using the latest AutoMapper NuGet available (2.2.1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AutoMapper;

public class A
{
    public int a { get;set; }
    public string b { get;set; }
    public List<int> ints { get;set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int a { get;set; }
    public string b { get;set; }
    public List<int> ints { get;set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<B, A>();
        var b = new B
        {
            a = 1,
            b = "foo",
            ints = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 })
        };

        var a = Mapper.Map<B, A>(b);
        Console.WriteLine(a.ints.Count);
        foreach (var item in a.ints)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

This console application maps between the 2 types as expected. So I guess that you haven't shown your real code. You will have to show a full example illustrating your problem.

Comment: yes I haven't shared my complete code as i am not allowed to, company policies, but i am not getting any value in a.ints

Comment: Well then maybe you could ask the politicians at your company to solve your issue. I have posted you a complete working example in my answer. If you are not allowed to show your code then go ahead and try to isolate the problem in a sample application, just as I did in my answer and then show it here. I don't see what kind of help do you expect if you are not telling us what code you are using.

Comment: i have added the actual code, please help me in fixing this problem

Comment: Hey Thanks, the problem is solved now. it was just because i have creaded a map for List<int> as well.